# whats the volume slider in the multitasking bar for?

Tags: ios

I have just upgraded to iOS 4.2.1 and I don't have an Apple TV so there's no Airplay button, however I still have a volume slider in the multitasking bar?

What volume does that change, and whats the point of it, I can just use the hardware buttons. (I'd much rather it was a brightness slider like there is on the iPad)

Comment: What device are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume changes the volume of the audio on your device, just like the hardware volume buttons do.

Comment: so theres no point in it?

Comment: @Jonathan - it depends on what app you are using and if that app offers a volume slider. Technically, there is no point, but there is little you can do. There is no way, AFAIK to change it into a brightness slider. Good luck!

Comment: well if the app doesnt have a slider you can use the hardware buttons

Comment: @Jonathan - true. I'm not arguing with you or defending Apple, I'm merely explaining how their design was implemented.

Comment: I know you weren't arguing. My keyboard run out of batteries and its very slow and aching to type with a mouse ;)